# Simplest django setup

Tags: python, django

I want to use django for a very simple project, basically a local project to navigate directories, and I'm basically just using it for its template language and ORM. I was wondering if I could do it all in a one-file setup as follows:

- `manage.py` (includes everything except html)
- `main.html`

This approach works for everything minus loading `django.models`, which I think assumes a settings file is already imported before calling it. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

### Settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "manage")
ROOT_URLCONF = 'manage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = '.'
DEBUG = True
DATABASES={'default':{'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql','NAME':'bookmarks','USER':'root','PASSWORD':'','HOST':'','PORT':'',}}
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', 'manage.main', name='main'),)

### Views
def main(request):
    from django.shortcuts import render
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'hello': "Hello"})


### Models
# from django.db import models <-- everything works except this line
# class Tag(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The error message I get is:

> File ".../django/db/**init**.py", line 11, in 
> if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:

Is there a simple way to get everything in one file?

Comment: I think your issue is that you are importing `models` before your settings have been configured, have a look at this project https://github.com/rnevius/minimal-django/blob/master/minimal.py I think if you call `settings.configure`, like this project, before importing models you may have more luck

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks that works, now my only issue is the `app_label` for creating the Model -- any idea?

Comment: You can set the app_label manually in the model Meta, might get away with just setting that, although I don't know what would be appropriate to use? I think you may have issues if you don't have a separate module/app when it comes to the ORM especially for things like migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to Iain for pointing in the right direction. Here are the full settings I'm using for the full application to work in one file, which can have any name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

### Settings
if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        ROOT_URLCONF=sys.modules[__name__],
        TEMPLATE_DIRS = '.',
        DATABASES={'default':{'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql','NAME':'bookmarks','USER':'root'}},
    )
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
urlpatterns = patterns(__name__, url(r'^$', 'main', name='main'),)

### Views
def main(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'tags': tags})

### Models
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    class Meta: app_label=''; db_table='tag'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv if len(sys.argv) != 1 else sys.argv + ['runserver',])
```